# Any way to prevent this code from crashing my game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code is meant to deform and damage a car model I have made except my model has a lot more vertices than the code can handle and as so crashes my game when the mesh comes into contact with any object. I don't think my PC is the issue as I have a 3080 and ryzen 5600x. Is there any way I can simplify the code to prevent it from crashing? It is C# for unity btw.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Deform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float deformRadius = 0.2f;
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float maxDeform = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float damageFalloff = 1;
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float damageMultiplier = 1;
    [Range(0, 100000)]
    public float minDamage = 1;

    private MeshFilter filter;
    private Rigidbody physics;
    private MeshCollider coll;
    private Vector3[] startingVerticies;
    private Vector3[] meshVerticies;

    void Start()
    {

        filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        physics = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (GetComponent<MeshCollider>())
            coll = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

        startingVerticies = filter.mesh.vertices;
        meshVerticies = filter.mesh.vertices;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        float collisionPower = collision.impulse.magnitude;

        if (collisionPower > minDamage)
        {
            foreach (ContactPoint point in collision.contacts)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Deformation(point));
                
            }

            UpdateMeshVerticies();
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Deformation(point)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < meshVerticies.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 vertexPosition = meshVerticies[i];
            Vector3 pointPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(point.point);
            float distanceFromCollision = Vector3.Distance(vertexPosition, pointPosition);
            float distanceFromOriginal = Vector3.Distance(startingVerticies[i], vertexPosition);

            if (distanceFromCollision < deformRadius && distanceFromOriginal < maxDeform) // If within collision radius and within max deform
            {
                float falloff = 1 - (distanceFromCollision / deformRadius) * damageFalloff;

                float xDeform = pointPosition.x * falloff;
                float yDeform = pointPosition.y * falloff;
                float zDeform = pointPosition.z * falloff;

                xDeform = Mathf.Clamp(xDeform, 0, maxDeform);
                yDeform = Mathf.Clamp(yDeform, 0, maxDeform);
                zDeform = Mathf.Clamp(zDeform, 0, maxDeform);

                Vector3 deform = new Vector3(xDeform, yDeform, zDeform);
                meshVerticies[i] -= deform * damageMultiplier;
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    void UpdateMeshVerticies()
    {
        filter.mesh.vertices = meshVerticies;
        coll.sharedMesh = filter.mesh;
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use a coroutine to do the deformation - copy the vertexes in to a temporary copy, deform them, once done then apply to the object.

Comment: @BugFinder how should I implement that into the code? I've never used a coroutine before

Comment: have a look at the unity documentation - its nice and simple.

Comment: @BugFinder I tried doing a coroutine but I'm not sure how to parse the variables through, I get an error: Cannot convert from unityengine.contactpoint to 'point'. I've edited the question with the updated code.

Comment: "IEnumerator Deformation(point) " wont compile, its not valid c#

Comment: @BugFinder So how should I go about doing the IEnumerator?

Comment: cant teach you c# over SO. its not the return type but your parameter thats wrong